# Attributes and polymorphism

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, overriding

I have 2 classes:

```
public class Increase {
public int a=3;
public void add(){
    a+=5;
    System.out.println("f");
}
}

class SubIncrease extends Increase{
    public int a=8;
    public void add(){
        a+=5;
        System.out.println("b" + a);

    }
}
```

But when I run

```
    Increase f=new SubIncrease();
    System.out.println(f.a);
    f.add();
    System.out.println(f.a);
```

I got this output:

```
3
b13
3
```

Could anyone help me to understand why this happens? The value of the a attribute was changed in method add, as shown by the second outpuy row...why does it get back to its original value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java, fields are not overridden, they are hidden. That means `Increase.a` and `SubIncrease.a` are *separate* fields that can be changed and queried separately. Because the type of your variable `f` is `Increase`, the expression `f.a` returns the value of the superclass field. But the `add()` method *is* overridden and `f.add()` calls the subclass method, which modifies the subclass field.

Hiding a field rarely makes sense, so you should avoid it. If you want to have a field with a different default value in a subclass, define it only in the superclass and assign a value to it in the subclass constructor.